# Question regarding coefficents regarding linear modeling in R

Tags: r, machine-learning-model, structural-equation-modelling

I had a question regarding the composition of coefficents of a linear model in R.

Let's say my model is as follows, with three columns/independent variables: X, Y, and Z.

And my model is: (X * Z) + (Y * Z).

Is this comparable to performing the transformation X * Z, Y * Z *before* modeling ? I.e. mutate() creating new columns 'XZ' and 'YZ', thus my new formula is just XZ + YZ ?

In my intuition, I want to say 'no', because when you're running the model, it is holding all other variables constant.

I just ask because if it were possible, this would greatly simplify my analysis -- plus, having the multiplication in the equation makes it unbearably slow in R (like, days), and provided the limited computing resources I have access to, restricts me to processing incredibly small sample data sets.

However, I know this equation is the result I am after.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> thus my new formula is just XZ + YZ ?

No, the `*` operator in R expands into all lower-order terms.

```
terms(~(X * Z) + (Y * Z))
```

Simply adding a product term to a formula can be accomplished with the `:` operator (not that I assume you want to do this, but it can be useful to know).

```
terms(~ X:Z + Y:Z)
```

See the `?formula` help page for details.